# How to use Gradle properties in Groovy project

Tags: gradle, groovy

Let's say I want to run Groovy code with Groovy plugin and pass properties to some groovy files. I know you can import properties from Maven build with `project.properties`. Just didn't figure out how to do it with Gradle build.

Comment: how do you want to run Groovy code? By simply writing it in the build file? Or by running the code in a file? Or during tests?

Comment: `task runScript (dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'code'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
task runScript(type: JavaExec) {
    main 'Main'
    systemProperty( 'my-prop', 'hello' )
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

In the groovy script (`Main.groovy`):

```
println 'my-prop is ' + System.getProperty( 'my-prop' )

// all properties
println System.properties
```

Comment: What do I write in my .groovy file to get this property ? Actually what I really need is getting all properties.

Comment: `System.getProperty( 'my-prop' )`

Comment: @minas Edited the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to define properties you need in `gradle.properties` file at the root of your project

```
myUserProperty=value1
systemProp.system=someValue
```

and then use it in `build.gradle` script

```
task printProperties << {
    println myUserProperty
    println System.properties['system']
}
```