# How to use values in gradle.properties in Groovy file

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm providing a simplified example of my workflow and confirmed behavior of the provided code in a fresh project:

In my `gradle.properties` I have a line:

```
testFilesPath=buildSrc/src/main/resources/testFiles
```

which references a folder at the stated path with 2 files, `testFile1.txt` and `testFile2.txt` underneath

I would like to use the gradle property in a Groovy class located at `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/TestDirectoryReader.groovy` like so:

```
class TestDirectoryReader {
    void printDirectoryContents() {
        def testFiles = new File(System.getProperty('testFilesPath'))
        testFiles.eachFile() { testFile ->
            println(testFile.name)
        }
    }
}
```

This class file isn't compiling - I'm getting an error:

```
> Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.String]
    [class java.net.URI]
```

During debug, I tried specifically evaluating `System.getProperty('testFilesPath')` and it returns with null, which would explain the error. So it seems like this isn't the way to retrieve the value from gradle.properties.

I found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258374/how-to-use-gradle-properties-in-groovy-project) but it doesn't quite seem to match my use case and I'm not sure I understand why I'd need to create a JavaExec task to get values specifically out of gradle.properties which I thought was meant to be accessible everywhere

Can someone provide me with an example of how I would access values from gradle.properties in my Groovy class please?

Comment: Use prefix `systemProp.` to define system property. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my `gradle.properties` line to read

```
systemProp.testFiles=buildSrc/src/main/resources/testFiles
```

and I call it in my Groovy class using

```
def testFiles = new File(System.getProperty('testFiles'))
```

Thanks @daggett!